# Vue2 when refreshing any page it redirects to the main page

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I was trying to work on vue2. and I am facing a strange problem.
I have 4 routes.

1. /login when user is not logged in they will see this page so they can log in.
2. /uploads when user login they are redirected to this page.
3. /train this page for some other work
4. /documents/collaboration when they use this router it should render train component only but url will be BASE_URL/documents/collaborate

My problem is when I refresh /train page or paste the collaborate url it redirects me to /uploads.

I am not able to know what is wrong with this and why this is happening.

Below is the code for my router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import LoginPage from './views/Login.vue'
import Uploads from './views/Uploads.vue'
import Train from "./views/Train";

Vue.use(Router)


export const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginPage,
      meta: {bodyClass: 'auth-wrapper'}
    },
    {
      path: '/', redirect: '/uploads'
    },
    {
      path: "/uploads",
      name: 'Uploads',
      component: Uploads,
      meta: {bodyClass: 'full-screen', verboseName: 'Data Classifier', icon: '@/assets/img/company5.png'}
    },
    {
      path: "/train",
      name: 'Train',
      component: Train,
      meta: {bodyClass: 'full-screen', verboseName: 'Data Trainer', icon: '@/assets/img/company5.png'}
    },
    {
      path: "/documents/collaborate/:id",
      name: "Collaborate",
      component: Train,
      meta: {bodyClass: 'full-screen', verboseName: 'Data Trainer', icon: '@/assets/img/company5.png'}
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/login'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user-token');

   if (authRequired && loggedIn === null) {
     return next('/login');
   }
   if (loggedIn !== null && !authRequired) {
     return next('/uploads');
   }
  next()

})

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to `/uploads` since the `if (loggedIn !== null && !authRequired) {...}` condition is **true** inside `route.beforeEach()`. Change:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   ...
   if (authRequired && loggedIn === null) {
     return next('/login');
   }

   // navigate to to.path() page
   next();
})
```

Comment: still the same issue if i used your code also. its still redirecting to /uploads.

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/login'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user-token');

  if (authRequired && loggedIn === null) {
    return next('/login');
  }
  next()

})

Comment: It should not be, can you share your updated codes?

Comment: ok, thanks. It would be a great help if you can provide [jsFiddle](jsfiddle.net) like example reproducing your problem.

Comment: Also, can you share the codes where `<router-view></router-view>` exists?

Comment: I can not post all my project in js fiddle it has python backend and all

Comment: Seems all is ok! You don't need to add real codes, just add minimum sample codes, and show the case live, so that we can find out the actual issue.